# Python Performance Build From Source

Tags: python

I need to build a performance (non-debug) version of Python, from source obtained from www.python.org/ftp/python.

On a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server, obtained the source for Python3.8 from under www.python.org/ftp/python and locally built and installed a local copy of it. Even earlier obtained a copy of it from `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, but found it to be 28% slower than the Python3.7 that I obtained via `sudo apt install python3.7`. Reported potential issue to bugs.python.org, via issue [38477](https://bugs.python.org/issue38477).  Python bug was closed as `not a bug`, because this is a reasonable performance regression when comparing a debug version of python to a performance. I agree, but so far have not been able to figure out how to locally build a performance version of Python, directly from the Python source.

```
# On a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server
# Install various needed prerequisites:
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev 
libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev

# Obtain and set gcc-8 as default compiler. Ubuntu 18.04 already comes
# with gcc-7
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc \
/usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8

# Obtain performance version of Python3.7.3 directly from Ubuntu package
$ sudo apt install python3.7

# Obtain and unpack local copy of Python3.7.3 source code
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo tar xzf ~/Python-3.7.3.tgz

# Build local version of Python3.7.3, from local copy of the source.
$ cd /usr/src/Python-3.7.3/
$ sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
$ sudo make altinstall

# Create a simple Python script to demonstrate the performance of
# each version.
$ vi ~/consume_cpu_cycles
$ cat ~/consume_cpu_cycles
import sys
print(sys.version)
for i in range(100000000):
  if not i % 20000000:
    print(i)
$ chmod +x ~/consume_cpu_cycles

# Execute the simple script to measure performance with both
# versions of Python3.7.3. Version at /usr/bin/python3.7, was obtained
# via "sudo apt install python3.7". Version at
# /usr/local/bin/python3.7.3 was produced from local
# build of Python3.7.3 source.
$ time /usr/bin/python3.7 ~/consume_cpu_cycles
$ time /usr/local/bin/python3.7 ~/consume_cpu_cycles
```

Expect the reported real ("wall-clock") time reported from executing via the Python version built from the downloaded source, to be better or at least nearly identical to that from the version obtained via `sudo apt install python3.7`.

Execution on my server produced:

```
lhuemill@c000n001:/usr/src/Python-3.7.3$ time /usr/bin/python3.7 
~/consume_cpu_cycles
3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 19:16:38)
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
0
20000000
40000000
60000000
80000000

real    0m9.936s
user    0m9.926s
sys     0m0.008s

lhuemill@c000n001:/usr/src/Python-3.7.3$ time /usr/local/bin/python3.7 
~/consume_cpu_cycles
3.7.3 (default, Oct 20 2019, 04:37:02)
[GCC 8.3.0]
0
20000000
40000000
60000000
80000000

real    0m11.790s
user    0m11.784s
sys     0m0.004s
```

In this case, running from the locally built version of Python is 18.7% ((11.79-9.936)/9.936) slower, then running under the same Python version obtain from an Ubuntu package. Ideally could always just obtain Python from a Ubuntu package, but I need to build directly from the source. For example, Python3.8 is not currently available as a Ubuntu package and the version from `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` appears to be a debug version (see Python issue 38477).

Comment: It is expected that you ask a question in your question.

Comment: @KlausD.: I think it's fairly clear that the OP wants to know how to build a version that is at least as fast as ones obtained from a Ubuntu package.